Microsoft Excel: Macro to repeat in different cells
I have this code which works well, however I need to expand this box set up to 4 different ones. This is listing out livestock and would be adding/pulling info from same sheet but different stock in each in each range.
So for example first box set may have "stock 224" and second box set may have "stock 225"
'On Livestock Change
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E19")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim Stockrow As Long
    If Range("E19").Value <> Empty Then
        If Range("B8").Value = Empty Then 'Not Existing livestock
            If MsgBox("The customer is not currently in the Livestock list. Would you like to add it?", vbYesNo, "Customer Not Found") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
            'Launch userform to add livestock
            
        Else 'Existing Customer Found
            Livestockrow = Range("B8").Value ' Livestock Row
            Range("L19:M19").Value = Livestock_List.Range("C" & Livestockrow).Value 'DOB
            Range("E20:I20").Value = Livestock_List.Range("D" & Livestockrow).Value 'breed
            Range("L20:M20").Value = Livestock_List.Range("E" & Livestockrow).Value 'EID
            Range("E21:F21").Value = Livestock_List.Range("F" & Livestockrow).Value 'Registered
            Range("I21").Value = Livestock_List.Range("G" & Livestockrow).Value 'Registrration
            Range("L21:M21").Value = Livestock_List.Range("H" & Livestockrow).Value 'Registrration Number
            Range("E22:I22").Value = Livestock_List.Range("I" & Livestockrow).Value 'SIRE
            Range("L22:M22").Value = Livestock_List.Range("J" & Livestockrow).Value 'Sire Registrration Number
            Range("E23:I23").Value = Livestock_List.Range("K" & Livestockrow).Value 'Dam
            Range("L23:M23").Value = Livestock_List.Range("L" & Livestockrow).Value 'Dam Registrration

        End If
        
    Else 'Is Empty
        Range("L19:M19").ClearContents 'Clear DOB
        Range("E20:I20").ClearContents 'Clear breed
        Range("L20:M20").ClearContents 'Clear EID
        Range("E21:F21").ClearContents 'ClearRegistered
        Range("I21").ClearContents 'Clear Registrration
        Range("L21:M21").ClearContents 'Clear Registrration Number
        Range("E22:I22").ClearContents 'Clear'SIRE
        Range("L22:M22").ClearContents 'Clear Sire Registrration Number
        Range("E23:I23").ClearContents 'Clear Dam
        Range("L23:M23").ClearContents 'Clear Dam Registrration

    End If

I attached a screenshot to show box sets. Any assistance is appreciated.
I tried repeating code which didn't work but I am not code savvy


Would be very helpful to include the row/column headers in your screenshot so we can relate the code to what's on-screen.  Also some unclear parts in your code.  What is Livestockrow the result of for example?  Looks like it's only a single value?

LiveStockRow was originally 1 Block of info (1 Stock) I am now needing to expand this to be able to enter a total of 4 different stock and not sure how I should write that.

Where are these 4 different stock?  How would you identify source rows on Livestock_List ?   Would be useful if your screenshot also had row numbers in addition to the column headers.

Thank you for so much patients as I lacked all the information to be able to help me. I updated Photo and also added Heading labels above the 4 different Livestock Information Boxes I need. I can get Livestock 1 to populate just fine cant get the other 3 to do add information.  Livestock_List is another sheet with all the livestock listed out on it. This is where the livestock information is coming from and will be placed in Livestock boxes as sold.

For the question as asked.
Create helper functions that will clear a set of cells. Any code here is totally untested and for illustrative processes only.
Private Sub UpdateLivestockRecord(livestockRow as long, rangeToFill as range)
' livestockRow has the same purpose as in the original code.
' rangetoFill is the first cell in the record to fix. There are other ways, but this is the easiest concept.
' r & c are place fillers, I have done the first two, you can work out the offsets from hereon
    Livestockrow = Range("B8").Value ' Livestock Row
    rangeToFill.Offset(0,7).Value = Livestock_List.Range("C" & Livestockrow).Value 'DOB
    rangeToFill.Offset(1,0).Value = Livestock_List.Range("D" & Livestockrow).Value 'breed
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Value = Livestock_List.Range("E" & Livestockrow).Value 'EID
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Value = Livestock_List.Range("F" & Livestockrow).Value 'Registered
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Value = Livestock_List.Range("G" & Livestockrow).Value 'Registrration
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Value = Livestock_List.Range("H" & Livestockrow).Value 'Registrration Number
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Value = Livestock_List.Range("I" & Livestockrow).Value 'SIRE
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Value = Livestock_List.Range("J" & Livestockrow).Value 'Sire Registrration Number
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Value = Livestock_List.Range("K" & Livestockrow).Value 'Dam
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Value = Livestock_List.Range("L" & Livestockrow).Value 'Dam Registrration


Private Sub ClearLivestockRecord(rangeToClear as range)
' rangetoClear is the first cell in the record to fix. There are other ways, but this is the easiest concept.
' r & c are place fillers, I have done the first two, you can work out the offsets from hereon
    rangeToFill.Offset(0,7).Clear 'DOB
    rangeToFill.Offset(1,0).Clear 'breed
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Clear 'EID
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Clear 'Registered
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Clear 'Registrration
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Clear 'Registrration Number
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Clear 'SIRE
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Clear 'Sire Registrration Number
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Clear 'Dam
    rangeToFill.Offset(r,c).Clear 'Dam Registrration

And then the event handler:
'On Livestock Change
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B19:B22")) Is Nothing Then ' Note can now check all input boxes at once
    Dim Stockrow As Range
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$B$19"
            Stockrow = ThisWorkSheet.Range("$E$19")
        Case "$B$20"
            Stockrow = ThisWorkSheet.Range("$E$19")
          .
          .
          .
    End Select
    If Target.Value = Empty or Target.Value = 0 Then 'which means user has just cleared data
        ClearLivestockRecord Stockrow
    Else
    'TODO: Perform check that value in Target.Calue is an existing record
    'TODO: The add a customer or not bit
        UpdateLivestockRecord Target.Value, Stockrow 
    End If


Frame challenge. A more effective way may be to use Excel native functions rather than VBA. The following function would be placed in the cells you want to fill.
=if(or(LivestockRow1 = 0,isblank(livestockrow1)), "", index(Livestocklist,match(livestockRow1, LivestockList,0),RelevantColumn))

This is totally untested, and you would have to change my named placeholders with the relevant cells (hint: use named ranges where you can). The relevant column will be the one that holds the bit of data you want to put into the cell (Livestock_List.Range("H" & Livestockrow).Value).
Now it becomes easy to duplicate this block in one Livestock record to the duplicated ones below - adjusting LivestockRow1 for LivestockRow2 etc.
The figures will update as the workbook is recalculated - when new data is put into those cells. No need for a change event.

Thank You... Place holder Name did correct it!
